# Why telegram does not send message to webhook?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

Using [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api#TelegramBot+setWebHook) on my VPS, I'm trying to get message from a telegram channel.

Here is the code:

```
var TelegramBot = require ( 'node-telegram-bot-api');
var token = '1793xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

var __dirname ='/etc/nginx/ssl'

var options = {
  webHook: {
    port: 443,
    key: __dirname+'/key.pem',
    cert: __dirname+'/crt.pem'
  }
};


var bot = new TelegramBot(token, options);
bot.setWebHook('1.3.4.5:443/bot1793xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', __dirname+'/crt.pem');


bot.on ( 'message', function (msg) {
    var chatId = msg.chat.id;
    console.log (msg);
    bot.sendMessage (chatId, "Hello!", {caption: "I'm a bot!"});

});
```

When I get this link the browser:

https://telegram.me/MyExampleBot?start=abcd

I expect the bot to receive a message from the channel containing `abcd` when user clicks on `start` button, but I receive nothing in the bot's console.
The problem occured when I added `bot.setWebHook` to the code. Without that, I could receive a message whenever user typed something in the channel.

My code is following the the example [here](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/examples/httpsWebHook.js) so I really have no idea what is wrong with it. Really appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Telegram didn't send anything to my bot...

Because of incorrect certificate. Generate your cert according to this:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed

just replace "YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE" with valid for you value. I used just my IP, after that it works.

Additionaly you can see debug info from node-telegram-bot-api to understand what happening:

> npm install debug 
>   DEBUG=node-telegram-bot-api node bot.js

It will produce debug output for you.

Hope it helps.